# Android Studio Regular Expression

Tags: java, android, regex

**I have this:**

```
 public final static boolean isValidNickName(String target)
 {
     return Pattern.compile("^.((?=.*[가-힣]).{1,12})((?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,12}).$").matcher(target).matches();
 }
```

and I would like the pattern to validate the followings:

1. Allow one letter or more from the range [가-힣].
2. Allow alphanumeric variation starting from 2 combinations ex)1a, 가1, 가a, 5bcc, 994930s0  are allowed
3. Exclude everythingelse (like special characters or a single alphanumeric character)

The application exits when I run this for now.

Also, I have this which is working:

```
    public final static boolean isValidPassword(String target) 
   {
        return Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{4,12}").matcher(target).matches();
   }
```

But this returns true when special characters are included

and I want it to return false when special characters are included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final static boolean isValidPassword(String target) {
    return Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12}$").matcher(target).matches();
}

public final static boolean isValidName(String target) {
    return Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z가-힣])[a-zA-Z가-힣]{1,}$").matcher(target).matches();

}

public final static boolean isValidNickName(String target) {
    return Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\\d])[a-zA-Z0-9가-힣]{2,12}$|^[가-힣]$").matcher(target).matches(); 
}
```

Here is the answer after 3 hours of struggling...

Answer (score 1):

This code maybe can help someone.

pay attention to Pattern.UNICODE_CASE

```
public boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {


    String regEx = "^(?:(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)[^\\s]{8,}$";

    CharSequence inputStr = password;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx,Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

    if(matcher.matches())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: In Java, strings are Unicode, so they may differ from ascii

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. May it Help..
// check password is valid or not
This character class

```
[\p{L}\p{No}\p{Space}]
```

will include all characters which Unicode declares as either "letters", "numbers", or "whitespace characters". If you want to match a string against such a character class, you would write the following:

```
input.matches("[\\p{L}\\p{No}\\p{Space}]+")
```

Comment: No.. there's not a difference in that way of syntax compared to mine

Comment: Okay. But this code works me fine. That's why I suggested you.

Comment: Does yours exclude @ ! and other special characters?

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I forgot that you have to exclude the special character, I have updated my answer. Please see.

Comment: Hmm it excludes numbers now.